# How to rollback a current Changeset to Particular Changeset by ChangesetID Using TFS API and C# code

Tags: c#, tfs, rollback

I'm trying to rollback from current changeset to particular changeset  using Changeset IDs, But nothing happens

Below is the code...

```
static TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(repository)); //e.g. repository = "http://..."
static VersionControlServer vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

Workspace ws = vcs.GetWorkspace(localWorkingPath); // localWorkingPath = @"D:\\Folder_Name";
ws = vcs.GetWorkspace(ws.Name, vcs.AuthorizedUser);

int fromCS = 10674; //changesetid
int toCS = 10672; //changesetid
VersionSpec versionSpecFrom = new ChangesetVersionSpec(fromCS);
VersionSpec versionSpecTo = new ChangesetVersionSpec(toCS);

var status = ws.Rollback(workigDnirectoryArr, RecursionType.None, null, versionSpecFrom, versionSpecTo, LockLevel.None, RollbackOptions.None, null);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Shayki for help to show image.